# How do I get the portal's current login URL in DotNetNuke?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, dotnetnuke

In the context of a DNN module, what's a good generic way to find out what the URL to the login functionality is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a utility method that gets the login URL:

C#

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the login URL for the given portal from the current <paramref name="request"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="portalSettings">The portal settings.</param>
        /// <param name="request">The request.</param>
        /// <returns>The URL for the login page</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">if <paramref name="portalSettings"/> or <paramref name="request"/> is null.</exception>
        public static string GetLoginUrl(PortalSettings portalSettings, HttpRequest request)
        {
            if (portalSettings != null && request != null)
            {
                int tabId = portalSettings.ActiveTab.TabID;
                string controlKey = "Login";
                string returnUrl = request.RawUrl;
                if (returnUrl.IndexOf("?returnurl=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
                {
                    returnUrl = returnUrl.Substring(0, returnUrl.IndexOf("?returnurl=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                }

                returnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl);

                if (!Null.IsNull(portalSettings.LoginTabId) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.QueryString["override"]))
                {
                    // user defined tab
                    controlKey = string.Empty;
                    tabId = portalSettings.LoginTabId;
                }
                else if (!Null.IsNull(portalSettings.HomeTabId))
                {
                    // portal tab
                    tabId = portalSettings.HomeTabId;
                }

                // else current tab
                return Globals.NavigateURL(tabId, controlKey, new string[] { "returnUrl=" + returnUrl });
            }

            throw new ArgumentNullException(portalSettings == null ? "portalSettings" : "request");
        }
```

VB.NET

```
''' <summary>
''' Gets the login URL for the given portal from the current <paramref name="request"/>.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="portalSettings">The portal settings.</param>
''' <param name="request">The request.</param>
''' <returns>The URL for the login page</returns>
''' <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">if <paramref name="portalSettings"/> or <paramref name="request"/> is null.</exception>
Public Shared Function GetLoginUrl(portalSettings As PortalSettings, request As HttpRequest) As String
    If portalSettings <> Nothing AndAlso request <> Nothing Then
        Dim tabId As Integer = portalSettings.ActiveTab.TabID
        Dim controlKey As String = "Login"
        Dim returnUrl As String = request.RawUrl
        If returnUrl.IndexOf("?returnurl=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1 Then
            returnUrl = returnUrl.Substring(0, returnUrl.IndexOf("?returnurl=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        End If

        returnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl)

        If Not Null.IsNull(portalSettings.LoginTabId) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.QueryString("override")) Then
            ' user defined tab
            controlKey = String.Empty
            tabId = portalSettings.LoginTabId
        ElseIf Not Null.IsNull(portalSettings.HomeTabId) Then
            ' portal tab
            tabId = portalSettings.HomeTabId
        End If

        ' else current tab
        Return Globals.NavigateURL(tabId, controlKey, New String() {"returnUrl=" + returnUrl})
    End If

    Throw New ArgumentNullException(If(portalSettings = Nothing, "portalSettings", "request"))
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Globals.LoginURL

```
public static string LoginURL(
    string returnURL,
    bool override
)
```

Comment: if returnURL has query string params (basically contains ?) then the method returns current page :(. Reproducible in DNN 6 & 7 it seems.

Comment: Actually the login address if fine. The redirect after login is not working when having query string params.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about DNN specific stuff but can't you just use the following property?

FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl

Here's the relevant MSDN page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.loginurl(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the ?ctl=login query string to get to the default DNN login page even if the default url has been modified..

```
string loginURL = string.Format("{0}://{1}/Default.aspx?ctl=login", 
    Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host);
Response.Redirect(loginURL);
```